# Returning a value which is inside of add on Success Listener in kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am facing a problem to get a return type in a function in kotlin

The function is

```
 override suspend fun uploaded_docs_retrival() : ArrayList<String> {

    Firebase.firestore.collection("profiles").whereEqualTo("uid", "$uid").get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        for (document in result) {
            val myObject = document.toObject(docretreving::class.java)
            val x = myObject.Docs
        }

    }
    return x
}
```

Here I am retrieving the information from Fire store Mapping it to a object

However in above Function I am unable to return x as it says x is unresolved

My data class is as Follows:

```
data class docretreving(
val Docs : ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf<String>()
```

)

How do I write the code in such a way that I can return value x which is a Array list from my function uploaded_docs_retrival()

Edit the below code worked :-

```
override suspend fun uploaded_docs_retrival() : ArrayList<String> {
    return try {
        val result = Firebase.firestore.collection("profiles").whereEqualTo("uid", "$uid").get()
            .await()
        result.first().toObject(docretreving::class.java).Docs
    } catch(e: Exception) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Failed to upload: ${e.message.orEmpty()}")
        ArrayList()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my function that calls an API return an empty or null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value) Because you already marked your function as suspend, I think my own answer in this question is the most relevant to your case.

Comment: You can also use a callback function and return the data with it.

Answer (score 3):

Call `await()` instead of adding a success listener. Wrap it in try/catch because it throws an exception on failure.

I'm not sure exactly why you're returning a single item when Firestore can return multiple. I'm just taking the first item in the results below:

```
override suspend fun uploaded_docs_retrival() : ArrayList<String> {
    return try {
        val result = Firebase.firestore.collection("profiles").whereEqualTo("uid", "$uid").get()
            .await()
        require(result.isNotEmpty()) { "No values returned." }
        result.first().toObject(docretreving::class.java).Docs
    } catch(e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to upload: ${e.message.orEmpty()}")
        ArrayList() // or you can rethrow or return null if you want
    }
}
```

If you don't have access to the `await()` extension function, add this dependency in build.gradle:

```groovy
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.6.0"
```

Comment: Thanks , isnotEmpty() reads a error   Error =  Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch                                                                             Any clue how do i get rid of that?

Comment: Check your capitilization.

Comment: yeh i just coped and pasted it ....It still says typemiss match ....isNotEmpty() thats the function i have

Comment: If you hover the cursor over `results`, what type does it tell you it is?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting 'x is unresolved' because the scope of 'val x' is within the for loop.

You won't be able to access it outside the loop and listener.

The best way to get list of strings, is to pass a listener as parameter to the method. You can also pass the 'SuccessListener' to get the values.

`override suspend fun uploaded_docs_retrival(listener : SuccessListener) = Firebase.firestore.collection("profiles").whereEqualTo("uid","$uid").get() .addOnSuccessListener(listener)`

Comment: This does not have to be a `suspend` function, also it returns a Task for some reason.