# Is there any special method that adding document of firebase into arrayList(Kotlin)?

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin

Hi I am stucked at adding the element in kotlin:arrayList.
That element is from documents of firestore.

Here is my code that I am having trouble with.

```kotlin
class AddActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val mainDataBase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("mainDB")
    val customDataBase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("customDB")

    private fun getMainList(): ArrayList<ExerciseDataBase> {
        val ret =  ArrayList<ExerciseDataBase>()
        var current: ExerciseDataBase
        mainDataBase.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                for (document in documents) {
                    current = document.toObject(ExerciseDataBase::class.java)
                    Log.d("yool",current.toString())
                    ret.add(current)
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.d("yool", "return fail", e)
            }
        Log.d("yool", ret.toString())
        return ret
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val addBinding = ActivityAddBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(addBinding.root)

        val list: ArrayList<ExerciseDataBase> = getMainList()
        Log.d("yool",list.toString())
    }
}
```

I checked my Log, and i found `Log.d("yool",current.toString())` works well. (by the way "yool" is my name, so just ignore it :p)
Here is the image of Log.

[image]

As you see, `Log.d("yool", ret.toString())` shows faster than `Log.d("yool", current.toString())`

1. I wonder how to get object from firestore documents. And add it to arrayList.
2. I wonder why `Log.d("yool", ret.toString())` shows faster than `Log.d("yool", current.toString())`. Please Help me :((

Comment: `current.toString()` isn't logged until the database get is successful.  `ret.toString()` is shown as soon as the database get is started.  And arraylists are just arraylists -- you just call `.add` to add something to them.

Comment: There are several duplicates to this question, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71592766/returning-a-value-which-is-inside-of-add-on-success-listener-in-kotlin) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594772/how-to-return-a-list-from-firestore-database-as-a-result-of-a-function-in-kotlin). This basically boils down to not understanding the asynchronous execution of callbacks. If you want code that looks sequential despite being async, you could use coroutines for it (but that also has its learning curve)